# How can I use for example SourceTree with a remote repository?

Tags: git, remote, version-control

I've a server with a folder. In this folder I've did a `git init` to create a git repository in this folder. When I open now a file in this folder and change something, the git notices this and mark it as a change.

To commit and push these changes I currently login to my server via SSH, navigate to the folder and run my git commands. Because I don't like this, I'm looking for a GUI which acts like an `SSH logon` and brings all the functionality given in the bash.

I've already tried SourceTree and GitKranken but this tools seems to be only working with a Bitbucket server or Github (whatever) but not with a normal git repo.

Do you have any idea how I can make my workflow better with a GUI?

Comment: Is a GUI an absolute requirement? I work remotely and I just ssh into the server in the morning and do all my work there. I have a GUI editor that can open remote files, but I run my git commands from the ssh session. Is that a decent workaround for you?